# Where does Windows 10 get its birthday calendar from?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, calendar, windows-10-calendar-app

Windows 10 sometimes displays [birthday reminder notifications](http://stackzilla.com/disable-birthday-notifications-in-windows-10-lock-screen-and-desktop/) on the lock screen and desktop. In some cases these reminders show for people I've never heard of before. Checking Windows 10's calendar app lists the birthdays [as an Outlook calendar](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/disable-birthday-notifications-on-windows-10/Images/Windows10-Calendar-Notification.png), despite me never using Outlook on my PC.

Where is Windows 10 pulling its birthday information from?

Comment: If it Microsoft account, it takes it from social networks. Check privacy settings.

Comment: I can't find anything about what accounts it's specifically pulling from. It seems to be pulling some of them from Skype, but I can't tell for sure

Comment: Skype - for sure. Check also WiFi Sense settings that share your WiFi by default with all your friends via facebook

Comment: As the site you link to in your question says:   "Because of integration with LinkedIn, other email services and social media sites anybody you have ever had a connection with has a birthday notification"

Comment: @mcalex: I knew Win10 could pull from social media sites. I was trying to figure out which specific services it was pulling from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook will grab the birthdays from the [contacts](https://outlook.live.com/owa/#path=/people) you have saved. As others have pointed out, you can get additional birthday calendars through connected social networks like Facebook and LinkedIn.

Comment: That seems to be it. Outlook was pulling birthday info from my Skype contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook or Windows 10 seem to pull birthdays from EVERYWHERE. People I don't know (or who have forgotten), people haven't heard of in decades, people from just about any social media site ever connected to. Its absolutely ridiculous, annoying and scary.
I've tried to find the list where these have been complied to several times but nobody seems to know where to edit this list, including people that work for Outlook and Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Look under "Notifications & Actions" in Windows Settings. You will see a list of notification sources with the option to edit each one.

[image: Settings Page]

Comment: How does this answer the question?